Run linux command from .net web api as request user
I'm running external process (bash) as a result of request to web api endpoint. Now it runs as Environment.UserName. Is it possible to start that process as: Request.HttpContext.User.Identity?
Current code which works but uses Environment.UserName user:
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "sh";
var argss = $"/test.sh";

process.StartInfo.Arguments = argss;

process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = false;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = false;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;

process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();

